# How to downsample image with custom kernel in opencv?

Tags: opencv, kernel, downsampling

I want to down sample image, but i don't want to use gaussian kernel.
Is there any opencv function for that purpose?

**UPDATE**:i have an image with size m by n. i want result image with size m/2 by n/2, such that:

```
result[i,j]=(
    a*input[i*2,j*2]+
    b*input[i*2+1,j*2]+
    c*input[i*2,j*2+1]+
    d*input[i*2+1,j*2+1]
    )/e
```

how can i do that efficiently with opencv?

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for [resize()](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=resize#resize).

From [wiki-downsampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downsampling):

> In signal processing, downsampling is the process of reducing the sampling rate of a signal. **This is usually done to reduce the data rate or the size of the data**.